# android and multiple running of the same application

Tags: android

I write application on android which will be runnig all the time on background. There will be only one starting view on first run. I want to user run instance of my app only once, and cant run any other instance at the time. When he try to run this app when one instance of this app is running already he sould see some warning notification. My problem is I dont know how to prevent user from multiple start of my app. Is this possible? If it is possible, how can I do it? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For background processing I would recommend to consider [Services](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/services.html). Services are created to deal with longterm background tasks. I think [foreground service](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/services.html#Foreground)(like Skype) may be interesting for you.
As Phil suggested you can you launch mode to control your activity behaviour. Consider using **launchMode = "singleTop"**

Answer (score 1):

You need to pick a [launchmode](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode) that will best fit your needs (probably *singleInstance* or *singleTask*). As for popping a notification, you can handle that in `onCreate` or `onResume`, however it doesn't have anything to do directly with how many instances are running.